# Problems when passing parameters of an Angular application for a Rails controller

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json, angularjs

I have an application made in angularjs, but I'm having trouble reading the parameters on the server side.

As I'm sending the data:

```js
api.factory('AuthProvider', function($resource, ENV){

  var baseUrl = ENV.apiEndpoint;

  return $resource(baseUrl, null,
    {
      login: {
        method: 'POST',
        url: baseUrl+'sessions'
      }
  });

});

angular.module('tuneduc.controllers.admin',[])
    .controller('AdminController', function($scope, $location, AuthProvider) {

        var auth;

        $scope.login = function (credentials) {

          auth = new AuthProvider(credentials)

          auth.$login(function(res) {
            console.log('success');
          },
          function(res) {
            console.log(res.data.errors);
          })

        }

    });
```

So the parameters are coming this way on the server:

```js
{"{\"email\":\"assdaf@adfasdf.com\",\"password\":\"sadfsdf\"}"=>nil, "controller"=>"sessions", "action"=>"create"}
```

I've tried using JSON.stringify () but failed.

Comment: This looks like it should post the correct parameters at the very least. What calls the `login` function from the AdminController and where do the `credentials` come from?

Comment: Problem solved, I do not know why, but after I inserted the OPTIONS route worked.